# GCSFuse keeps generating dummy files on mounted bucket that can't be deleted due to retention policy

Tags: fstab, gcloud, gcsfuse

I'm currently setting up a GCP storage bucket on my instance which will be used for backups. I have currently configured fstab to mount the bucket on startup using the following config.

`cpanel1-vm-backups /mount/backups gcsfuse rw,user`

The problem is that GCSFuse keeps generating random files which it can't delete due to the retention policy on the bucket so I end up with hundreds of files with randomly generated filenames in my bucket.

After disabling the retention policy the random files stop appearing in the bucket but I need to have this retention policy in place for redundancy reasons.

Any recommendations to resolving this?

Comment: It is not common of FUSE to be generating this random files, what are their names?

Comment: They appear to be UUID strings.
- f7a61166-18e8-4d8d-8a8b-73c74a3869c6

I think GCSFuse is generating files to test the connection. It looks like my backup software needs write access to existing files anyway so I'll just have to look into other methods of securing my backups

Comment: These are probably files created by the software you are using, I tested it just now and did not have any files constantly created. Keep in mind that using retention policies with FUSE adds an additional limitation on how you interact with the mounted directory, for your use case I agree that this is not the optimal setup.